# Setting a C# WPF program to start on boot

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, startup

I have created a WPF application in C# that functions as a new lock screen that caters to me (because it makes me feel more esteemed), and obviously for a custom lock screen I would need it to start on boot. Now, I DO have an SSD in my machine, but the time it takes for my program to start from the time the desktop loads is outrageous for a custom lock screen (using the "shell:startup" method). Is there any more optimized or prioritized way for me to load the program on startup?

Comment: Does setting a program to start on boot have anything to do with what kind of program it is?  C# and WPF tags likely don't belong.  Just mention that it has a window, which will require that the user is logged in (not just that the system is booted.)

Comment: I'm sure it does. If you want you can show that in an answer and I would gladly accept it.

Comment: So far, I'm convinced it doesn't matter at all what kind of program it is.  If it is a windows program that creates a window, then just add it to your startup programs as the answer in the linked question suggests.  And if there's any reason the answers there don't answer your question, then edit your question with the reason and we'll see if it's worth re-opening.